# ngClass is not being applied inside angular data table?

Tags: angular, ng-class, angular-datatables

Below code not applying ngClass.

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceAB">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Type">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="(element.TxnType=='Credit')?'text-success':'text-danger'"> {{element.TxnType}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsAB"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsAB;"></tr>
/table>
```

I am getting the proper data to dispaly but class is not applied. Wts wrong ??

Comment: try `===` in place of `==`

Comment: initially hard code [ngClass]="'text-success'" and ccheck the result if this is working then try as said in previous comment

Comment: did you add `text-success` and `text-danger` in css?

Comment: Conditions are working correctly ,text-success and danger are part of bootstrap,have you imported bootstrap? or you created custom named classes in css ?

Comment: tried === and already imported bootstrap..its still not working ??

Comment: Please post the stackblitz code so that one can check and let you know

Comment: sorry guys..the problem is , i used 'Credit' instead of 'credit'..mat table is auto capitalizing first letter in 'credit' string and so i thought it was 'Credit'

Answer (score 3):

add `text-success` and `text-danger` in css

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngclass-is-not-being-applied-inside-angular-data-table?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**

**Component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceAB" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="(element.TxnType=='Credit')?'text-success':'text-danger'"> {{element.TxnType}}
            </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsAB"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsAB;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry guys..the problem is , i used 'Credit' instead of 'credit'..mat table is auto capitalizing first letter in 'credit' string and so i thought it was 'Credit'